# How to display a popup only once per day vue

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have a method that shows a modal window 4 seconds after the user logs on to the site. If it is closed then show again next 24 hours. I have some problems. LocalStorage does not store my data and does not return a variable that stores the date, how can I fix it?

```
mounted () {
    this.runModalTimer()
    this.setDevHoursModal()
  },
  methods: {
    runModalTimer (): void {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.isModalVisible = true
      }, 4000)
    },
    setDevHoursModal (): boolean {
      if (localStorage) {
        let nextPopup = localStorage.getItem('isModalVisible')

        if (nextPopup > new Date()) {
          return this.isModalVisible = true
        }

        let expires = new Date()
        expires = expires.setHours(expires.getHours() + 24)

        localStorage.setItem('isModalVisible', expires)
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `setDevHoursModal` method,  you're not always returning a value.  You could resolve this by just returning the result of the condition:

```
setDevHoursModal(): boolean {
  if (localStorage) {
    let nextPopup = localStorage.getItem('isModalVisible');
    if (nextPopup > new Date()) {
      return (this.isModalVisible = true);  // let's be a little more explicit here
    }

    let expires = new Date();
    expires = expires.setHours(expires.getHours() + 24);

    localStorage.setItem('isModalVisible', expires);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I still have a problem with if (nextPopup> new Date ()) {
and 
expires = expires.setHours (expires.getHours () + 24), can't compare date and line. How can I solve this?

Comment: @ВладСоснов In your retrieval of the item, you need to wrap it in a constructor: `new Date(localStorage.getItem('isModalVisible'))`